# Keep getting error in my SQL code - "Column Invalid"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t-sql, left-join, where-clause

I keep getting an error when I use this SQL code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        SELECT tblTempPacing.PROJ_ID, tblTempPacing.FSR, tblProjectInfo.CUSTNAME, tblProjectInfo.TITLEDESC, 
        tblProjectInfo.CSYN, tblProjectInfo.PROJSTATUS, tblProjectInfo.RELEASETYPE, tblRevenueModel.Rev_Rec_Model, tblRevenueModel.CM_Percent, 
        SUM(tblSubledger.Sales), tblCalcCurrQtrEstRev811Old.CQER_Total_Revenue, SUM(tblSubledger.GE_True_Cost), tblActualsAndEstimates.CurrQtrEstCosts, tblSubledger.Year, tblSubledger.Quarter

        FROM tblTempPacing LEFT JOIN tblProjectInfo ON tblTempPacing.PROJ_ID = tblProjectInfo.PROJ_ID
        LEFT JOIN tblRevenueModel ON tblTempPacing.FSR = tblRevenueModel.FSR
        LEFT JOIN tblCalcCurrQtrEstRev811Old ON tblTempPacing.FSR = tblCalcCurrQtrEstRev811Old.FSR
        LEFT JOIN tblSubledger ON tblTempPacing.FSR = tblSubledger.FSR
        LEFT JOIN tblActualsAndEstimates ON tblTempPacing.FSR = tblActualsAndEstimates.FSR

        WHERE tblRevenueModel.Rev_Rec_Model = 'SOP811' AND tblSubledger.Year = 2017 AND tblSubledger.Quarter = 4;
```

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015. The SQL is part of an SQLCommand.

[image: My Error Message]

[image: The column is **tblTempPacing.PROJ_ID** is real]

Comment: `I keep getting an error` How do we know what was the error

Comment: From what I'm seeing, I think you get an error because you are a missing a group by clause in your query,  since you are using the sum() in your select clause you must add group by